# Ambiguous method in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bukkit

In Bukkit's API, there are two functions that show up as ambiguous when I try to call them

```
int getMaxHealth()
double getMaxHealth()
```

I can't figure out how to specify to the compiler which function I want to call. Instead of directly comparing like

```
if (getMaxHealth() < 40d) { /* Code */ }
```

I tried "directly" assigning the variable

```
double health = getMaxHealth();
```

However, both cases result in IntelliJ complaining that it is an ambiguous method. How can I fix this?

Comment: maybe you get a jar with error, where is the jar location?

Comment: It's not an error, both methods exist to provide backwards compatibility to older plugins

Comment: Which class or interface do these methods belong to ? I am taking a look at the [Bukkit API](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/) and i can only find the interface `Damageable` which has a method `int getMaxHealth()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I can still compile the program even though there is an error. So I guess that fixes the problem!

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ often can help you solve the problem. Put your cursor on the code which is marked incorrect and then press Alt+Enter (if you have the Windows version, don't know the key combination on other OS ...). The IDE might suggest a solution to you.

Comment: On Mac, it's command + 1. Although there is no suggested action by IntelliJ on this particular error sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Overloaded methods are determined with their parameter list. Changing return type does not change the signature of method from compiler's view-point. So Java's compiler is complaining about redefining same method which is not allowed and it has nothing to do with IntelliJ or Eclipse.

Comment: You should either change the name of the method or pass a parameter. You can't have two methods with same name in one class. I mean something like: `getMaxHealthInt()` and `getMaxHealthDouble()` or `int getMaxHealth(int input)` and  `double getMaxHealth(double intput)`

Comment: If all you need it to get a max health value, why you don't use int version always? JVM will implicitly convert it to double where is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can fix this.

If I write, using Eclipse, code as yours:

```
int getMaxHealth() {return 1;}
double getMaxHealth() {return 1d;}
```

It even does not compile. Both methods are marked as duplicates.